# Finding a good docker image for Python 3

Tags: python, docker

I am learning how to use Docker and I am trying it with a few things I'm doing with Python.

I found a few official images for Python on dockerhub.com [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/).

But I saw the warning sign "This image has vulnerabilities" and I'm not sure if the official image is safe to use.

Just wondering if there is a better choice or I should safely ignore the warning and just use it for production sites.

Cheers.

Comment: Where did you see that error message? It's not there now. Maybe they already updated to fix that.

Comment: I tried it again and found that if you did not log in, you won't see the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

[Docker security scanning](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/image-scan/) results help you determine if an image is secure for your purposes. You can click on the tag name to open up the detailed scan results. For example, [2-alpine3.7](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/2-alpine3.7/) has one vulnerability identified for the ncurses package that is installed. The vulnerability description explains:

> CVE-2017-16879
>   Stack-based buffer overflow in the _nc_write_entry function in tinfo/write_entry.c in ncurses 6.0 allows attackers to cause a denial of service (application crash) or possibly execute arbitrary code via a crafted terminfo file, as demonstrated by tic.

You can select a tag that will work for you. The vulnerabilities in the Python images haven't stopped tens of millions from pulling it, but you must decide based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I can click in to see the details. I appreciate your advice.